WIN32 Menu Bar Color with Dark Mode
I'm updating an old WIN32 app to support dark mode. After creating the window I do the following:
DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &ncrp, sizeof(ncrp));
BOOL value = TRUE;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, &value, sizeof(value));

I now have a window frame and title bar that draw in the correct color (following the system dark mode setting). However, the menu bar is still drawn in a light color.

All menus are created programatically, not using a resource file. There's no custom drawing happening. Is there a way to get the menu bar to draw correctly without having to custom draw it?

"All menus are created programatically" - can you show that code? Which menu API(s) are you using?

The menus in plain Win32 cannot change their color. You have to either use an owner drawn menu, or use WinUI3.

Some Windows development frameworks, such as Windows App SDK, support Dark mode natively and change certain UI elements without any additional code. Win32 apps often don't support Dark mode. If you want to change the color of the menu bar you need to custom draw it or try to use Windows App SDK. Refer to the Doc:Support Dark and Light themes in Win32 apps
And you could refer to the thread:https://github.com/tauri-apps/muda/issues/97
